# simplifying limits of rational equation

Tags: limits

Why does $\lim \frac{-h}{(x+h-1)(x-1)}$ as $h$ aproaches $0$ get multiplied by $\frac 1 h$? My text says simplify and it multiplies that rational expression by $\frac 1 h$, why is that?

original problem:
differentiate f(x) = $\frac{x}{x-1}$

Comment: They are using $f^{\prime}(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}(f(x+h)-f(x))\cdot(1/h)$.

Comment: what kind of function is giving?

Comment: Please state the original problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula is $f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)+f(x)}{h}$

For your f(x) it is $$f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{x+h}{x+h-1}-\frac{x}{x-1}}{h}$$

Expand the fraction by $(x+h-1)(x-1)$ gives $$f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(x+h)(x-1)-(x+h-1)\cdot x}{h\cdot (x+h-1)(x-1)}$$

Multiplying out: $$f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{x^2-x+hx-h-x^2-xh+x}{h\cdot (x+h-1)(x-1)}$$

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-h}{\color{blue} h \cdot (x+h-1)(x-1)}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-h}{ (x+h-1)(x-1)}\cdot \frac{1}{\color{blue}h}$$

To answer your question. The h in the denominator comes straight from the formula.

Comment: Ok, but how does it get on the same level as the denominator of the numberator?

Comment: @user183621 I have a problem to understand your question, especially the word level in this context. It is possible, that you rephrase your question ?